# RabbitMQ message persistency : difference between lazy queue and persistent delivery mode

Tags: rabbitmq, persistence, high-availability

I'm setting up a RabbitMQ (v3.8.0) cluster with High Availability.

To enable messages persistency, I set exchanges and queues **durable** parameter to True.

```json
{
    "exchanges": [
        {
            "name": "my_direct_exchange",
            "vhost": "my_vhost",
            "type": "direct",
            "durable": true,
            "auto_delete": false,
            "internal": false,
            "arguments": {}
        }
    ],
    "queues": [
        {
            "name": "my_queue_direct",
            "vhost": "my_vhost",
            "durable": true,
            "auto_delete": false,
            "arguments": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

Then, it seems there are 2 choices :

- Either sending messages with **delivery_mode=2**
- Or, setting **lazy mode** in queues (via policy configuration)

```json
"policies": [
        {
            "vhost": "my_vhost",
            "name": "my_policy",
            "pattern": "",
            "apply-to": "all",
            "definition": {
                "ha-mode": "all",
                "ha-sync-mode": "automatic",
                "queue-mode": "lazy"
            }
        }
    ]
```

Both of these choices will stores messages on disk. 
What is the difference between them ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> To enable messages persistency, I set exchanges and queues durable
> parameter to True.

To clarify, the `durable` parameter for exchanges and queues does not affect ***individual*** message persistence. The `durable` parameter ensures that those exchanges and queues survive broker restarts. True, if you have a non-durable queue with persistent messages, and restart the broker, that queue and those messages will be lost, so the `durable` parameter is important.

You should use the `persistent` flag, even with lazy queues. Why? Because you should also be using [Publisher Confirms](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html#when-publishes-are-confirmed), and a message will only be confirmed when written to disk when `persistent` is set.

Comment: Thanks ! So, is lazy mode useless when `persistent` flag is on ?

Comment: Little late to the party, but I thought I'd answer the above comment: persistent messages will survive a broker restart, lazy means it will write out to disk ASAP to keep memory pressure low, but without `persistent` these messages will be lost on restart. Together, these two features, make good bedfellows!